# updating values in excel column depending on two other columns being equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets. In the first I have a few columns, namely part numbers, prices, descriptions and so on.

In the second sheet, I have 2 columns with a select few part numbers and their new prices.

I require a way to go through sheet 1 and compare it to sheet 2 part numbers. if they are there same, the prices in sheet 1 need to be updated with the prices in sheet 2.

I have searched but nothing completely covers this or at the least, i lack the understanding since I'm new to excel.

Hope I can get some assistance, thanks!

Comment: Look into using `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Which columns are the part numbers and the prices occupying on Sheet1? Ditto for Sheet2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option for the macro

```
Sub update()
Dim cell1, cell2, col1, col2 As Range

For Each cell1 In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
If IsEmpty(cell1.Value) Then Exit For
    For Each cell2 In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
        If IsEmpty(cell2.Value) Then Exit For
        If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(cell1.Row, 2) = _
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cell2.Row, 2)
        End If
    Next cell2
Next cell1
End Sub
```

If you are new to programming just prest Alt+F11, press insert > New Module and copy and paste any of the codes provided.

PS. Excel Hero's option will consume a bit less memory

Answer (score 0):

If your first sheet holds the 'master' list of parts and the second sheet holds a smaller list that is for updating the master list with new prices, then formulas alone are not going to be the solution.

To overwrite the prices on the master sheet, you will need a VBA macro.

This macro will do the prices update assuming colums A and B are used for the parts and prices on both sheets:

```
Public Sub UpdatePrices()

    Dim m1, m2, u1, u2, i&, j&

    m1 = Sheet1.[a1:index(a:a,counta(a:a))]
    m2 = Sheet1.[b1:index(b:b,counta(a:a))]
    u1 = Sheet2.[a1:index(a:a,counta(a:a))]
    u2 = Sheet2.[b1:index(b:b,counta(a:a))]

    For j = 1 To UBound(m1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(u1)
            If u1(i, 1) = m1(j, 1) Then
                m2(j, 1) = u2(i, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Sheet1.[b1].Resize(UBound(m2)) = m2

End Sub
```